# Selenium utilizando Python

Tags: python-3.x

Estou fazendo um bot que vai percorrendo uma página até chegar na onde baixa um arquivo, porém não consigo acessar um link utilizando o `driver.find_element_by_xpath`, pois o link da pagina está como `href` e não possui uma classe para q eu identifique. Segue abaixo meu código:

```html
<a href="https://www.excelcontabilidade.com.br/tabela-de-correcao-monetaria/indicadores"><a/>
```

Meu código em Python:

```
WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"""//*[@]]""")))
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//[*href="https://www.excelcontabilidade.com.br/tabela-de-correcao-monetaria/indicadores""]""").click()
```

Alguém sabe me informar como acesso o hiper-link sem uma classe, `id` ou `name` definido?

Comment: Esse XPATH parece estar errado.
Para pegar o XPATH correto, abra a pagina, clique com o botao direito e clique em "inspecionar elemento" ou algo do tipo.
Dentro do 'inspecionar elemento', selecione esta parte do código onde tem o elemento que voce quer pegar, clique com o botão direito e selecione "Copiar -> xpath"

Answer (score 0):

Sem classes e sem nenhum tipo de identificação, apenas colocando o conteúdo (o link) dentro do href, igual neste código (o que, caso o site mude o link, pode acabar ocasionando erros no seu código):

```
variavel = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="https://www.excelcontabilidade.com.br/tabela-de-correcao-monetaria/indicadores"]')
variavel.click()
```

Ou simplesmente `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="https://www.excelcontabilidade.com.br/tabela-de-correcao-monetaria/indicadores"]').click()`

Sempre verifique os erros gerados no console quando for rodar o selenium para identificar erros, teste o código que te passei e se gerar algum erro me avise!

Answer (score -3):

Todas as tags a usa o `title`, você pode fazer assim:

```
find_element_by_xpath("//a[@title='https://www.excelcontabilidade.com.br/indicador/TJ-Maranhão']")
```

Depois diz se deu certo